# Can you Multiattack twice with the Extra Attack Feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, multi-classing, multiattack

Assume the character build Any Monk 5/Moon Druid 2, wildshaped into a Brown Bear:

On their turn, can they use their attack action twice to multiattack?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. Extra Attack doesn't give you two **Attack** *actions*, it gives you two attacks *per* **Attack** action. A 5th-level monk still only has one **Attack** action.

That means that not only do you not get two **Multiattack**s, but if you take the **Multiattack** action you don't get a second attack from Extra Attack either, because only the **Attack** action triggers Extra Attack's benefits.

Comment: This is probably a good thing, considering that would be 54 damage per turn on average with a string of two brown bear multiattacks, followed by a flurry of blows, assuming all the hits connected.

Comment: @Dumpcats "Attack action" is different from "attack"

Answer (score 12):

The Monster Manual (p. 9) says:

> **ACTIONS**
>
> When a monster takes its action, **it can choose from the
> options in the Actions section of its stat block** or use one
> of the actions available to all creatures, such as the Dash
> or Hide action, as described in the Player's Handbook.

If **Multiattack** is one of those options; then the druid is choosing the Multiattack action, not the Attack action and does therefore not meet the prerequisites of any class that give Extra Attack.

If the Druid is currently a Brown Bear and wishes to attack on their turn they can choose the following actions:

- Multiattack and get 1 bite and 1 claw attack
- Bite and get 1 bite attack
- Claw and get 1 claw attack
- Attack and get as many attacks as their class(es) allows which can be any of Bite, Claw or Unarmed or a substitute (Shove, Grapple etc.).

Comment: Does this answer also negate the possibility of using Flurry of Blows with Multiattack, considering there is a distinction between an attack and a multiattack?

Comment: Yes a Multiattack (like Hide or Dash) action is not the Attack action