# Can a monster that gains an additional action use multtiattack twice in that turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions, multiattack

I was reading the *Devourer* stat block from *Volo's Guide to Monsters* and noticed that one of his actions (Imprison soul) states:

> ...the devourer regains 25 hit points, immediately recharges Soul Rend, and
>   gains  an  additional action on its next turn. *VGtM page 138*

That made me wonder if a devourer can use **Multiattack** twice on his next turn.

I can't find anything in the **Multiattack** rules that prevent this, but it feels weird.

Answer (score 13):

### Yes.

This is, in effect, no different from the Fighter's **Action Surge** class feature:

> On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your
>   regular action and a possible bonus action.

Since the Attack action uses an action, he can effectively use **Action Surge** to Attack action twice in one turn.

In addition, the **Extra Attack** class feature grants [multiple attacks per Attack action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/73809/9399), which behaves similarly to the **Multiattack** action that some creatures have.

We know that **Multiattack** is an action a monster can take.  If a monster has two actions, then it stands to reason it can **Multiattack** twice if it has two actions, in the same way that the Fighter can Attack action twice with **Extra Attacks** when using **Action Surge**.